# Python regular expression ipaddress

Tags: python, regex

I've done some research and see the pattern for regular expression to match ipaddress is

```
pattern = r'\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}'
mo = re.findall(pattern, line(s))
```

but I'm trying to figure out what the comma is meaning instead of a dash i.e `\d{1-3}`

Thanks!

Comment: `{min,max}` is a [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). A dash is not correct here.

Comment: Thanks for the article.

So just to clear it up for me. the comma just means, 1 to 3 numbers, but the pattern doesn't take into account numbers greater than 255.

Comment: `\d{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 digits. Any digit. It will match `999`.

Comment: I know ip range would never hit number greater than 255 but how would you make the pattern more specific to the ip range?

Comment: See [this page, *IP Addresses* section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)